# RegExp_Replace everything after a certain list of words in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have a list of 200 +words in a column.
I want to replace anything which comes after those words.

```
Eg: E Graham St       DDS  ==> E Graham St
    Trent Ave      4DF ===> Trent Ave
```

Examples of words are AVE, ST ....
I am thinking of passing that string to a function and inside the function will have regexp replace.

Comment: Is this actual string: "E Graham St       DDS  ==> E Graham St"?

Comment: No the string is only the first part before '===>'    E Graham St       DDS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use something like:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace(str, '^((.*? ave[ \.])|(.*? st[ \.])|(.*? rd[ \.])|(.*? close[ \.])).*$', '\1', 1, 1, 'i')
  2   from (select 'E Graham St       DDS' str from dual
  3         union all select 'Trent Ave      4DF' from dual
  4         union all select 'Foo bar Rd. asd' from dual
  5         union all select 'E Graham St St DDS' from dual);

REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'^((.*?AVE[\.])|(.*?ST[\.])|(.*?RD[\.])|(.*?CLOSE[\.])).*$','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E Graham St
Trent Ave
Foo bar Rd.
E Graham St
```

Comment: And what about `W Mohave St DDS` ?  :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ah yeah. added a space to deal with partial words getting picked up

Comment: I need to address the following situation also 'E Graham St St   DDS'

Comment: @RajA try the amended version. the `?` converts it to non-greedy so it stops on the first match

Comment: Thanks a lot I did include that now..Thanks again..I have one more scenario. 'E Graham St Ave DDS' should become  'E Graham St'

Comment: Also can it be written as ^(.*? ave[ \.]|.*? st[ \.]|.*? rd[ \.]|.*? close[ \.]).*$', '\1', 1, 1, 'i')